# object with array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm trying to create an array of objects within another object and decide the magnitude of the array.

Why I get an error when I try to assign "obj2T" to "obj2"?

Pastebin code link: https://pastebin.com/kujujP5N

What is the correct syntax for creating an array of objects within another object and decide the magnitude of the array?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class classe2
{
    public:
        classe2();

    protected:

    private:
};

class classe1
{
    public:
        classe1(int value);
        void setClasse()
        {
        classe2 obj2T[grandezza];
        obj2=obj2T;
        }

    protected:

    private:
        const int grandezza;
        classe2 obj2[];
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
C:\cppProjects\project\main.cpp||In member function 'void classe1::setClasse()'
C:\cppProjects\project\main.cpp|22|error: incompatible types in assignment of 'classe2 [((classe1*)this)->classe1::grandezza]' to 'classe2 [0]'
```

Comment: There are no vectors in your code. There are arrays. And they cannot be assigned.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot sorry, edited.

Comment: You either create dynamically or use a vector instead.

Comment: @stark an exemple please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
#include <vector>

...

class classe1
{
    public:
        classe1(int value) :
            obj2 (value)
        {
        }
    private:
        std::vector<classe2> obj2;
};
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! This is exactly what I was looking, I apologize for the ignorance, I did not know this library ... Looking for the vectors I find only arrays online.

Comment: You're right... you know recommend me a complete and updated book?

Comment: @nostyn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Thanks so much :)